# Can't download Xcode anywhere, but I have used it for a couple of days ago. But now it doesn't work

Tags: xcode, download

I have deleted Xcode from my MacBook Air because I somehow deleted Xcode Beta. But when I try to re download it, it doesn't work. I've tried it through the developer.apple. But the I receive a message that I don't have enough memory. And when I try to download it from Appstore the GET button is grey instead of blue and I can't click it. And that is where I got it the first time.

Does anyone have a clue for me what to do. I am panicking.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough memory?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to write that. I only have 4,6 GB but I were thinking that because of that it worked before that it would work again, but I think that's the problem. Why it worked before I don't really. Do you know if iCloud memory works for apps. Because then I can buy 50GB memory..@AndreyChernukha